# Monodevelop 4.0.1 strange font on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, fonts, monodevelop

The font for everything but the actual script is all messed up in Monodevelop 4.0.1 on my new iMac running El Capitan. I have tried other solutions suggested on these forums and elsewhere including deleting monodevelop preferences and giving read/write access to everyone in Get Info but nothing is working so far. Other bugs mention boxes for characters but that is not my issue. See screenshot. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there another way to fix this font issue?

[image]

Comment: It might be a corrupted font on El Capitan.  Try opening the Font Book app and selecting File - Restore Standard Fonts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Ward for the tip in the comments. It looks like when I moved fonts over from my old system to my new iMac, I added a corrupted font. File -> Restore Standard Fonts solved the issue.